# html menu overlay Java applet

Tags: java, iframe, applet

I need to have an html/javascript navigation menu open and overlay a java applet. I have tried countless tricks from the web, but none seem to work well with the 3 major browsers: IE, Firefox, and Safari. Here is what I've done so far:
I have the applet in an html page with this in the body tag:

```
<applet code="arcClientJava.class" height="100%" width="100%"></applet>
```

I have the code for the navigation menu in another html page, which calls the applet through an iFrame:

```
<iframe src="applet.html" style="position:absolute; z-index:0;height:500;width:100%"></iframe>
```

The menu still hides below the java applet. Please help!